# Is there a good online database with a web GUI?

Tags: database, cloud

I'm trying to find a good online/cloud database that has its own web-based GUI. If possible, I would like to find one that has APIs so I can access the data programmatically, but still has a nice frontend that allows users to log in and edit records. I know Google's Fusion Tables do this, but the interface is clumsy and difficult to use for a real database.

I haven't been able to find anything else like this... can someone make a recommendation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I know RackSpace Cloud has recently rolled out their Cloud Database service. I have had very good experience with their Cloud service (Cloud Server, and Cloud Files/CDN). However I have no experience with their Cloud Database service.

[RackSpace Cloud Database](http://www.rackspace.com/cloud/public/databases/)

Comment: Thank you for the link. This is kind of what I'm looking for, but I want something that allows editing the data and running queries through a web interface.

Comment: You could always install PHPMyAdmin to point to your cloud database.

Comment: That's true, though I'm really surprised there's no cloud database solution that caters to both developers and users. Fusion Tables seems to be unique in that regard.